# How do I perform a check with over 1000 if statements?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I have a list of newspapers and magazines. It counts to 1374 to be exact and all my files are named like `abcd_20190406.xml`, where `abcd` is the filename abbreviaton and 20190406 is the date in `yyyyMMdd` format.

So what I want is that, if I press the button in my WindowsForm, it will search for the `abcd` in the list. If found, it will fill it's respective data which will be mentioned in my form's `TextBoxes`.

```
if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cboSource.Text).StartsWith("aamfr"))
{
        TextBoxPublication.Text = "Anti-âge Magazine";
        TextBoxAbbreviation.Text = "aamfr";
        TextBoxLanguage.Text="fr";
}

if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cboSource.Text).StartsWith("wic"))
{
        TextBoxPublication.Text = "Wisden Cricket Monthly";
        TextBoxAbbreviation.Text = "wic";
        TextBoxLanguage.Text="en";
}
```

And so on. This is my current approach. Giving 1374 if conditions. So is there a faster way or a more better way of doing this?

I thought of creating a `List<string>` and doing it but I have no clue how to proceed. I don't even know if that is the correct way of doing this.

Please help.

Comment: Use a list which holds the data for Publication, Abbreviation and Language

Comment: I assume you have some source for the Text, Abbreviation and Language rather than typing it from your own knowledge, so process that source to generate the data and store it in a table inside a database or a collection rather than writing 1734 * 3 entries by yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a class to hold the information for each publication, for example:

```
class PublicationInfo
{
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation{ get; set; }
    public string Language{ get; set; }
}
```

Then use a dictionary to hold all your publications

```
var Publications = new Dictionary<string,PublicationInfo>();
```

and fill it with your data, using the abbreviation as the key.
You will then be able to fill your text boxes like this:

```
var abbreviation = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cboSource.Text).Split("_")[0];
if (Publications.ContainsKey(abbreviation)
{
    TextBoxPublication.Text = Publications[abbreviation].Title;
    TextBoxAbbreviation.Text = abbreviation;
    TextBoxLanguage.Text = Publications[abbreviation].Language;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Encapsulate logic in the class, which makes you code easily to maintain.
When you decide to add or remove magazines you don't need to change your code in the class - Open-Close Principle isn't it?

```
public class Magazine
{
    public string Publication { get; set; }

    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }

    public Func<string, bool> Predicate { get; set; }
} 

private List<Magazine> _magazines = new List List<Magazine>
{
    new Magazine
    {
        Publication = "Anti-âge Magazine",
        Abbreviation = "aamfr",
        Language ="fr",  
        Predicate = source => source.StartsWith("aamfr")       
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var magazine = 
    _magazines.Where(mag => mag.Predicate(cboSource.Text))
              .DefaultIfEmpty(new Magazine())
              .First();

TextBoxPublication.Text = magazine.Publication;
TextBoxAbbreviation.Text = magazine.Abbreviation;
TextBoxLanguage.Text= magazine.Language;
```

Predicate function will provide more flexible approach, where every magazine can have different predicates, not only `StartsWith`.