# How do I add data to Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a list of newspapers and magazines. It counts to 1374 to be exact and all my files are named like abcd_20190406.xml, where abcd is the filename abbreviaton and 20190406 is the date in yyyyMMdd format.

So what I want is that, if I press the button in my WindowsForm, it will search for the abcd in the list. If found, it will fill it's respective data which will be mentioned in my form's TextBoxes.

```
if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cboSource.Text).StartsWith("aamfr"))
{
        TextBoxPublication.Text = "Anti-âge Magazine";
        TextBoxAbbreviation.Text = "aamfr";
        TextBoxLanguage.Text="fr";
}

if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cboSource.Text).StartsWith("wic"))
{
        TextBoxPublication.Text = "Wisden Cricket Monthly";
        TextBoxAbbreviation.Text = "wic";
        TextBoxLanguage.Text="en";
}
```

And so on. This is my current approach. Giving 1374 if conditions.

I have the following code:

```
class PublicationInfo
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}

var Publications = new Dictionary<string, PublicationInfo>();

var abbreviation = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cboSource.Text).Split('_')[0];
if (Publications.ContainsKey(abbreviation))
{
    TextBoxPublication.Text = Publications[abbreviation].Title;
    TextBoxAbbreviation.Text = abbreviation;
    TextBoxLanguage.Text = Publications[abbreviation].Language;
}
```

I want to add data in the dictionary.

My input data is as follows:

[image: input-data]

Please help.

Regards

Comment: What's your add logic from `if` statement?

Comment: @D-Shih - As shown in the question, that is my add logic. Individual conditions.

Comment: @John - It is the lsit of titles that I need to display. It is a requirement. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How do dictionaries come into it? How do your if statements come into it?

Comment: Please refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556154/how-do-i-perform-a-check-with-over-1000-if-statements. You will understand. My question is related to the question in the provided link.

Comment: Please include all necessary information in _this question_.

Comment: Could you show some data from the file?

Comment: @D-Shih - Edited the question with input

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Add or TryAdd method:

```
var abbrevation = "wic";
Publications.Add(abbrevation, new PublicationInfo{
   Title = "Wisden Cricket Monthly",
   Abbrevation = abbreviation,
   Language = "en"
});
```